# How do convert the postgreql query object into json in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am using nodejs and postgresql. If I use this code

`client.query("SELECT * FROM manlalaro WHERE premiumexpiry = DATE '2009-09-19' ",(err,res)=>{
   console.log(err,res)
   client.end()
})`
I get this response
[image]

`client.query("SELECT * FROM manlalaro WHERE premiumexpiry = DATE '2009-09-19' ",(err,res)=>{
   console.log(JSON.parse(res).rows)
   client.end()
})`

When I tried to retrieve the "rows" key using JSON parse. I get this result
[image]

I am not sure if DB server replied back a json. If it is, how do I parse it in nodejs?

Comment: The result is an object. There is nothing to parse.

Comment: Please [do not post code as images](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: can I make it into a JSON?

Comment: @Aedric It's *already* JSON. `res.rows[0]` to get the first row, `res.rows[0].userid` to get the first row's userid field, etc... Also you haven't blanked out the passwords in the screenshot.

Comment: @404 thanks! I got it now. maybe, I am just overthinking. thanks again!